# Prove that $\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^5\right)^{1/5}\geq \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

Tags: calculus, summation

> Show that if $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are positive numbers then $\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^5\right)^{1/5}\geq \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

I'm a little stuck on this question. I think I might need to use convex functions. I know the left sum is equal to $\dfrac{1}{n^5}(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^5)^{1/5}$. There are rules like $(a+b+c+d+\dots)^2 = a^3 + b^3 +c^3+d^3+\dots$ for consecutive integers $a,b,c,d,...$. This is very easy to show using induction, though I don't think induction will be very useful here.

edit: apparently Jensen's inequality could be useful.

Comment: How can this be true for $n>1$? Take $x=(1,0)$ then the left hand side is ${1 \over \sqrt[5]{2}}$ and the right hand side is ${1 \over 2}$.

Comment: What do you think, given my example?

Comment: Slightly perturbing copper.hat's example produces a counter-example as well, so zero terms rarely harm his/her point. Indeed, the proposed inequality is true only when $x_i$'s are constant. What is true is the following reversed one: $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\leq\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^5\right)^{1/5}$$ holds for any non-negative real numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, and the equality holds if and only if $x_i$'s are all equal. This follows from Jensen's inequality and the strict convexity of $x \mapsto x^5$.

Comment: I see that the inequality has been edited to change $\leq$ to $\geq$.

Comment: @Michael: The question was edited and the inequality reversed.

Comment: @copper.hat : Yeah, I noticed that a few seconds after I commented, so I deleted teh comment and added the above

Comment: Given that this is now an instance of Jensen's inequality, you may follow the standard argument. Write $m=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ for the mean and show that $$x^5\geq 5m^4 x-4m^5, \qquad x \geq 0. $$ Then average this inequality over $x=x_1,\cdots,x_n$ to conclude.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Proof_of_power_means_inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Hölder's inequality: for nonnegative $x_i, y_i$ following holds
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p \right)^{1/p} \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{p^{'}} \right)^{1/p^{'}},
$$ 
where
$$
\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^{'}} = 1, p>1.
$$

One can take $y_i = 1$, $p = 5$ and get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^5 \right)^{1/5} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n 1^{5/4} \right)^{4/5} =  n \cdot \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^5 \right)^{1/5}.
$$
Dividing both sides by $n$ gives the result
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^5 \right)^{1/5}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^5$, then f''(x)=20x^3>0, for x>0, so from Jensen's inequality ir follows that
$$\frac{f(a)+f(b)+f(c)}{3} \ge f(\frac{a+b+c}{3}).$$
$$\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{3} \ge (\frac{a+b+c}{3})^{5}$$ and hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

One may also use Tchebecheff's inequality repeatedly. If $a \ge b \ge c $ and $p \ge q \ge r$, then $$(ap+bq+cr) \ge \frac{(a+b+c)(p+q+r)}{3}~~~~(*)$$ We have
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge \frac{(a+b+c)(a+b+c)}{3} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3} ~~~(1)$$ Next $$(a^3+b^3+c^3) \ge \frac{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{3} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{9} ~~~(2.$$
Finally from (*), (1) and (2) we get 
$$(a^2~a^3+b^2~b^3+c^2~c^3)\ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{3} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^5}{81}.$$ Or
$$\frac{a^5+b*5+c^5}{3} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^5}{3^5}$$